# sublime text - how to order package settings dropdown list

Tags: package, settings, sublimetext3, sublimetext

Does anyone know how to alphabetically order Sublime Text 3's package settings dropdown list ?

[image]

Comment: https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/alphabetic-sorting-packages-list/21872